# SymmetricAlgorithm Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, encryption

I am getting `Length of the data to decrypt is invalid` exception without any real reason using this code

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension generic method that encrypts a byte[] using the specified SymmetricAlgorithm.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The SymmetricAlgorithm to be used.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The value to encrypt.</param>
/// <param name="password">The password for encryption.</param>
/// <param name="salt">The salt for encryption.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static byte[] EncryptBytes<T>(this byte[] value, byte[] password, byte[] salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(password), salt);
    SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();
    byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
    byte[] rgbIv = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);
    ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIv);

    using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                writer.Write(value);
            }
        }
        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Extension generic method that decrypts a byte[] using the specified SymmetricAlgorithm.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The SymmetricAlgorithm to be used.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The value to decrypt.</param>
/// <param name="password">The password for decryption.</param>
/// <param name="salt">The salt for decryption.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static byte[] DecryptBytes<T>(this byte[] value, byte[] password, byte[] salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(password), salt);
    SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();
    byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
    byte[] rgbIv = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);
    ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIv);

    using (var buffer = new MemoryStream(value)) {
        using (var stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
            stream.Read(value, 0, value.Length);
        }
        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Extension generic method that encrypts a string using the specified SymmetricAlgorithm.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The SymmetricAlgorithm to be used.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The value to encrypt.</param>
/// <param name="password">The password for encryption.</param>
/// <param name="salt">The salt for encryption.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string EncryptString<T>(this string value, byte[] password, byte[] salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptBytes<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), password, salt));
}

/// <summary>
/// Extension generic method that decrypts a string using the specified SymmetricAlgorithm.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The SymmetricAlgorithm to be used.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The value to decrypt.</param>
/// <param name="password">The password for decryption.</param>
/// <param name="salt">The salt for decryption.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string DecryptString<T>(this string value, byte[] password, byte[] salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DecryptBytes<T>(Convert.FromBase64String(value), password, salt));
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing to `stream`? Shouldn't you be reading instead?

Comment: @owlstead so what should i do ? i am totally confused when it comes to returning a byte[] from a decrypt functions

Comment: Use a `StreamReader` if the plaintext is a string. If it is binary, read from the `CryptoStream` directly.

Comment: Note, that attackers can modify the data without you noticing. They cannot know what the encrypted data is, but they can still modify it. They can even flip individual bits under certain circumstances. Use authenticated encryption.

Comment: @usr the password is generated by a DH Key Exchange between the server and the client. Is this enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StreamReader` if the plaintext is a string. If it is binary, read from the `CryptoStream` directly.

Comment: I will post my encryption function too so you can safely edit it for me to work with byte[]s ?, i am sorry but i got everything complicated and it would be nice to leave it for crypto professionals. Can i ?. It would provide a nice help for anyone else wanting to do the same as me.

Comment: Please use the `StreamReader` as you are using a `StreamWriter` at the encrypt function.

Comment: through my code what i want to achieve is to have a function that takes a byte[] and encrypts it and returns the encrypted array, and the same for decryption. Also i want to take a string and do the same so any ideas to make the code more reliable (actually working).

Comment: i would really appreciate a working version of my code to help me and anyone coming after.

Comment: Remove readers and writers. No need to do anything with strings in that case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49697/discussion-between-owlstead-and-runes)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string processing to process binary data. Remove `StreamWriter`.

More concretely, you are writing a `byte[]` to a `TextWriter` which makes no sense. In fact, it will be written as `value.ToString()` which is not what you expected.

Probably, you also better use the overload of `new Rfc2898DeriveBytes` that takes just `byte[]`. Again, strings are confused with bytes.

Comment: so how to return the decrypted byte[] directly from the CryptoStream ?

Comment: Maybe use `Stream.Copy` to copy the contents into a `new MemoryStream`, then call `MemoryStream.ToArray`.

Comment: @usr, Can i post the whole code because i kinda missed up the whole process as i am only a crypto beginner ? i can learn a lot from a working code instead

Comment: Ah, didn't see the password being passed as bytes, apologies about that. But it is not likely to be the culprit.